# An Array with multiple entries per index (an array of arrays?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

Can I make an array that has multiple pieces of data per row?

Almost like an excel spreadsheet so rather than having

```
NSArray *sampleArray1 = @[@"Name1",@"Name2",@"Name3"];
NSArray *sampleArray2 = @[@"Age1",@"Age2",@"Age3"];
```

and having to return the `[indexPath row]` of each array into your table view cell, you could instead have:

```
NSArray *superArray = @[@"Name1"|@"Age1", @"Name2"|@"Age2",@"Name3"|@""];
```

which would return all of your information for the selected index at once.

I am familiar with how you could do this in Swift. I would normally create a `struct` and give it a few array variables.

```
struct superArray {
    var names = [String]()
    var ages = [String]()
}
```

and I could simply do `cell.myLabel = superArray.names.indexPath[row]`

When I setup my tableview I need to return something for the number of rows the table should display. Currently in my Objc project I have just implemented dummy arrays and all the arrays are the same size, I'm returning only one of these. This in my eyes is bad because I could retrieve a dataset with incomplete parameters (maybe an age but not a name) then my table will see the wrong amount of information in my array and not display correctly.

Comment: Why not just create an User object that have name and age? Then just use 1 array to store them, thinks you should learn more about OOP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a very basic issue to solve. You want to store objects in your arrays containing these elements, e.g.

```
@interface User: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;

@end

NSArray<User *> *users = @[...];
```

It seems like you may need to learn a bit more about Objective-C. SO is more about helping you solve specific/complex problems, but I hope I've at least set you on the right track.

Comment: Got it, it kind of escaped me that an array can contain any object. I was just thinking in terms of integers and strings etc. I've implemented this into the project I wanted and everything works fab! cheers